# Django: Is there a way to filter out 503 'service unavilable' responses from mail_admins log handler?

Tags: django, logging, http-status-code-503

I have django LOGGING configured with standard "mail admins on 500 errors":

```
'mail_admins': {
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
    'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
},
```

When I put site into maintenance mode (django-maintenance-mode), it correctly responds with 503 "Service Unavailable" for anonymous requests.  This causes a barrage of emails to admins when the site is in maintenance mode.
I want to "filter out 503 response IF site is in maintenance mode" to stem the flood.
But can't see a simple way to do this (e.g., logging filter would need request to check if site in maintenance mode)

I know I could change the maintenance error code to a 400-level error, but that seems like non-semantic hack.  Could also suspend admin emails during maintenance, but that requires remember to hack / revert settings file.  Hoping someone has a clever idea how to achieve this simply, no hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create filter '**require_not_maintenance_mode_503**' in LOGGING of your settings.py and add the filter in handlers '**mail_admins**'. This will prevent sending email on 503 error. For example:

```
    LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_not_maintenance_mode_503': {
            '()': 'maintenance_mode.logging.RequireNotMaintenanceMode503',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_not_maintenance_mode_503'],
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that and mark this as correct answer if it works.  Much appreciated!

Comment: How passed a test of the solution on your environment? Any help needed?
On my environment works perfectly.

Comment: This works perfectly and is documented here:
 https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-maintenance-mode#logging

Note that v.0.16.2 resolved issue so filter now works regardless of how site was put into maintenance.  Thank you @schum and all package contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can suggest a hacky method. You can create a class that inherits the AdminEmailHandler class.

```
class CustomAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    def send_mail(self, subject, message, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'service unavailable' in subject.lower(): # Not sure about the condition, you can find the correct one by debugging.
            super().send_email(subject, message, *args, **kwargs)
```

Don't forget to change the class of mail_admins to new one in settings.

Comment: Oh ya.  That's good idea.  But still have no way to check if the system is in maintenance mode without access to the request object.  I don't want to universally block such errors, only those caused by intentionally putting site into maintenance mode.  Thanks for the idea - something to chew on.

Answer (score -1):

You could just set DEBUG=TRUE while site is in maintenance mode -- I mean, it's right there in your logging config.
DOH!

Still, requires mod'ing settings file and then remembering to mod it back when taking out of maintenance.  A bit hacky, but seems pretty simple otherwise.

Comment: Enabling DEBUG in production can have a whole bunch of side effects, like exposing settings and stack traces in an error page. Therefore it is not recommended.